# Downloading a complete html

Tags: r, html-parsing

I'm trying to scrape some website using R. However, I cannot get all the information from the website due to an unknown reason. I found a work around by first downloading the complete webpage (save as from browser). I was wondering whether it would be to download complete websites using some function. 
I tried "download.file" and "htmlParse" but they seems to only download the source code.

```
url = "http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g2216639-d2215212-Reviews-Ayurveda_Kuren_Maho-Yapahuwa_North_Western_Province.html"

download.file(url , "webpage")
doc <- htmlParse(urll)
ratings = as.data.frame(xpathSApply(doc,'//div[@class="rating reviewItemInline"]/span//@alt'))
```

Comment: According to the [terms of use](https://www.tripadvisor.com/pages/terms.html), it is forbidden to do so without permission. Do you have?

Comment: They make a exception if its for a purely education purpose

Comment: `rvest` is one of the packages which is often recommended for parsing XML and HTML. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/rvest.pdf

Comment: Also the package `httr` might be useful for you. The `httr::GET` function extracts body content as well as other information of your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked with rvest first go.

```
library(plyr)
library(magrittr)
library(stringi)
library(rvest) 

review_nodes <- html(url) %>% html_nodes('div.rating.reviewItemInline')

llply(review_nodes, function(i){
    data.frame(
        nth_stars = html_attr(html_nodes(i,'img'), 'alt'),
        date_var = stri_replace_all_regex(html_text(i), '(\n|Reviewed)',''))
    )
})
```

Comment: Error in llply(html(url) %>% html_nodes("div.rating.reviewItemInline"),  : 
  could not find function "llply"

Comment: wow this was from 2016, `llply` is from `plyr` if memory serves me correctly. 
`> environmentName(environment(llply)) #[1] "plyr"`.

Comment: not im pretty sure you could just use `lapply` and `jsonlite::rbind_pages` for this